# How to suppress inline function used but never defined warning in g++

Tags: c++, g++, warnings

**Context:**
I'm doing some compile time programming which involves manipulating types using constexpr functions that are only evaluated in a decltype context.

For example a pop function that removes the first type from a list of types:

```
template <typename T0, typename... T1toN>
constexpr auto pop(List<T0, T1toN...>) -> List<T1toN...>;
```

These functions are used like this

```
decltype(pop(my_type_list))
```

In other words, they are never 'executed'. Yet, the compiler (g++) gives me warnings such as `warning: inline function ‘constexpr List<T1toN ...> pop(List<T0, T1toN ...>) [with T0 = Type1; T1toN = {Type2, Type3}]’ used but never defined`

EDIT: It turns out the the warning only appears when the functions are evaluated in a decltype indirectly. i.e. A top level function which is only evaluated in a decltype uses a subfunction. results in a warning for the subfunction. 
Jarod42 created a nice reproduction scenario [here](https://godbolt.org/z/53By4m)

**Question:** Is there any way I can suppress this used but never defined warning? And is it possible to only do it for functions evaluated (indirectly) in a decltype context?

I am using g++ version 8.3

Comment: It would be more normal to define traits like this with structures or classes

Comment: I agree that using structs is the way it used to be done. But now that constexpr is getting more and more powerful, I find it often produces more readable code, even if you are just doing type manipulation. 
I started using this type of programming after watching a cppcon talk on compile time regular expressions from Hana Dusikova: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dKWdJzPwHw    It really shows how powerful this way of expressing these type manipulations is. (especially as things get more complicated and you have different functions calling each other. It is nice to have normal looking code)

Comment: Cannot reproduce warning [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Y2hegE).

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried to create  minimal example, but I guess I stripped out too much. In my real code the pop function is called from a different function. This other function is only evaluated in a decltype. Perhaps this indirect usage confuses the compiler. Will look at creating a piece of code that produces the warning in compiler explorer after work

Comment: Reproduced with your indication [here](https://godbolt.org/z/53By4m). and provide fix. I let you edit your question if it matches your issue. (feel free to reuse code/link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
template <typename ...> struct List{};

template <typename T0, typename... T1toN>
constexpr auto pop(List<T0, T1toN...>) -> List<T1toN...>;

template <typename T0, typename... T1toN>
constexpr auto pop2(List<T0, T1toN...> l) { return pop(l); } // You use pop

constexpr List<int, int> my_type_list;
using type = decltype(pop2(my_type_list));
```

[Warning demo](https://godbolt.org/z/53By4m)

`pop2` should not have definition, and be:

```
template <typename T0, typename... T1toN>
constexpr auto pop2(List<T0, T1toN...> l) -> decltype(pop(l));
```

Comment: Your post gave me the hints to solve it slightly differently: In my specific situation the top level function (called pop2 in your example) is quite complex and hence needs to have a definition. What I did was changed the calls to pop in that function to decltypes. That is, I replaced "return pop(myTypeList)" with "return decltype(pop(myTypeList){}". This then indeed solved the problem!

Answer (score -2):

If you are compiling in C++17 (or later!) mode, then you should be able to mark the function as [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused):

```
template <typename T0, typename... T1toN>
[[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto pop(List<T0, T1toN...>) -> List<T1toN...>;
```

If you aren't using C++17 or if you don't mind using gcc/g++ specific attributes, you could try [`__attribute__((unused))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes):

```
template <typename T0, typename... T1toN>
__attribute__((unused)) constexpr auto pop(List<T0, T1toN...>) -> List<T1toN...>;
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. The compiler is not flagging the function as unused, but instead it is saying that it is used, and complaining there is no definition. (Which should not be needed if it is only evaluated at part of a decltype statement)